# PHP + Mail Command + Sendmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have an issue which is stumped me for some time now, regardless of where I look, I cannot find an explanation for what I am seeing.

I have a server which sends out via a script, multiple emails based upon certain criteria. If a job encounters an issue, such as missing clients (between two systems), or missing product codes (between two systems), or if it updates the legacy system from the newer system with orders. Now these scripts run for a number of locations across Europe: Helsinki, Lulea, Stockholm and Oslo.

My conundrum is that for Stockholm and for certain events, no emails are being sent out! They are for other locations and other events both, but there is two which go AWOL. When I say go AWOL, I make it sound like they are sent but never received, the truth is that they don't actually leave the server in question.

The PHP Mail command is producing an error when it tries to send to Stockholm for two events, this is captured by monitoring the return of the PHP mail command and logging if the return is false. Looking at the sendmail log files for entries, both the output and the error, for the same time as the failed PHP Mail command is issued, there aren't any! Having enabled PHP Mail logging, I can see that it is issuing the command okay, but for some reason the command isn't running properly.

I've changed the description of the location, but that made no difference and considering some events did send emails, it didn't surprise me. Having logged the failed Mail command, I also log the subject line and the body of the email within a file. If I transpose those into a standalone test mail file, using identical code to the main script, it works fine.

Had the issue been a random one, then I would expect to see failures for other locations and other events, but they aren't. I've considered that the subject line was too long, but there are longer and it then shouldn't go through my standalone test mail script. I've changed the order in which the locations are dealt with, but again, it is very consistent in it failing for the same reasons.

So in summary:

- One location for two events isn't sending any emails out, but other events and locations are.
- The PHP Mail command is failing and returning a FALSE error code.
- The PHP Mail log file is showing the mail command being called.
- The sendmail log files do not record the failed mail commands, either in the err or normal output, although I can see all of the other successful emails.
- Amending location name does not make a difference, but it wouldn't since other events are being sent okay.
- Populating a test script with the subject and body of the failed email, sends okay (test script is identical to the main script).
- Changing the order of the locations being called by the script, makes no difference (the script deals with a single location at a time).

Any ideas as to where to look, what to check next, I'm all eyes and ears. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using PHP's native `mail` function then am sorry there is no easy way to get the actual issue/error because of which mail is not being sent. To look into your issue, can you please share the mail command? Also, if it possible for you to use [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) give it a try to debug the issue

Comment: Maybe this can help https://mikeberggren.com/post/48826934174/sendmail-debug - you can try producing a debug log file.

Comment: which transport are you using for sending mails, via SMTP login or the linux's Sendmail or Postfix?

Comment: Checkout this post, if something helps https://pritthish-nath.medium.com/configuring-spf-dkim-and-dmarc-with-sendmail-on-ubuntu-18-04-41edfd24fdd2

Comment: @PritthishNath it does not matter what transport I am using, since the PHP mail command is failing, but only on two emails, all other emails are being sent fine. However, it is using sendmail configured to the companies SMTP server.

Comment: @Haridarshan, yes unfortunately am I using PHP native mail command, and suffering for it. The code in question is one that I've inherited, which I'll need to look at using PHP Mailer within.

Comment: @JimGrant As you've mentioned mails are going through test script but not through main script, so can you please share your mail script both test and actual one

Answer (score 0):

I must thank those who have replied to my question, however, I have finally gotten to the crux of this issue (he says crossing his fingers).

Whilst the PHP mail command was failing, but only for a particular location, I decided to see what PHP thought the error was. This was achieved by inserting the code:

```
        if($success === true)
            echo("Email sent @ ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - $to, $subject".PHP_EOL);
        else
        {
            echo("Unable to send email @ ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - $to, $subject".PHP_EOL);
            print_r(error_get_last());
        }
```

The printing of the "error_get_last()" revealed that the sendmail command couldn't be executed:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => mail(): Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i '
    [file] => /var/www/html/dataloader/angleConvertClass.php
    [line] => 205
)
```

Looking into why this may happen, I stumbled across a post somewhere talking about memory usage and the lack of available memory can cause external programs to not execute. So I decided to see how much memory the PHP script was consuming just before the mail command was issued.

```
        try
        {
            print "\n--> PHP Memory usage ".memory_get_usage(true)." bytes <--\n";

            $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $header_string);
            $local_db->setMessageSent($to.$body);

            if($success === true)
                echo("Email sent @ ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - $to, $subject".PHP_EOL);
            else
            {
                echo("Unable to send email @ ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - $to, $subject".PHP_EOL);
                print_r(error_get_last());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $exc)
        {
            echo("Email failed big time @ ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."! $to, $subject".PHP_EOL);
            echo $exc->getTraceAsString().PHP_EOL;
        }
```

Leaving it a while I then rechecked the log file and found that the PHP script was consuming over 32GB of memory! The server has 32GB of main memory and 6GB of swap, so I'm guessing there is enough for the script to run, but not enough to start executables.

I do hesten to add, this is software that I've inherited as opposed to penned and a bit loathed to rewrite it since it was a temporary fix to a problem 2 years ago. The code loads in results from a database from a legacy system to compare against results from a new system, using very large arrays. Ergo the huge memory footprint!

I've requested that the main memory of the server be increased from 32GB to 64GB, as that will be infinitely cheaper than a rewrite and test of the code. Hopefully that will fix the problem.